# Why is the following frame buffer incomplete in OpenGL 4.5?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I'm attempting to create a cube map texture to render depths information for shadow mapping. I have encountered that my frame buffer is incomplete. In particular, it returns a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT` which according to the documentation means that there is not at least one image attached to it.

The code is:

```
GLuint depth_map;
GLuint FramebufferName;
void Renderer::create_shadow_map()
{
    //TODO: change render program here
    glUseProgram(0);
    FramebufferName = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

    glGenBuffers(1, &depth_map);

    const unsigned int SHADOW_WIDTH = 1024, SHADOW_HEIGHT = 1024;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, depth_map);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 
                            SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL); 

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depth_map, 0);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE); // No color buffer is drawn to.
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)==GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT)
            cerr << "shadow map not ok" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

A call to `glGetError()` allowed me to identify that the problem is the line `glFrameBufferTexture()`.

So I assume I am either not generating the buffer correctly or I am not attaching it to the framebuffer as I should.

Comment: What is the error returned by `glGetError` after `glFrameBufferTexture`?  The only thing I notice is that when `glFrameBufferTexture(..., depth_map, 0)` is called `depth_map` is already bound to `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`.  Not sure if that's allowed or not.

Comment: If you want to create a texture, then `glGenBuffers` isn't the right method. How about `glGenTextures`?